# How do I convert constraint layout to Relative layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-relativelayout, android-constraintlayout

I am currently trying to convert my constraint layout to relative layout, but not sure how to deal with "app:" parameters which refer to constraints top of, bottom of etc. Here's my code for clarification:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/myFragmentConstaintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/activeSpeakerContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/groupList"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myStatusContainer">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/activeSpeakerVideo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/black" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/activeSpeakerImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="48dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:src="@drawable/my_default_profile" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myParticipantCountText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_rect"
            android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:drawablePadding="2dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:textColor="@color/gray6"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/drawable_user_count_icon"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/drawable_user_count_icon"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_mark"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/image_mark_blue" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activeSpeakerName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#AA555555"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:lines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/gray6"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            tools:text="user@gmail.com" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/DurationText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="start|bottom"
            android:lines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/gray6"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            tools:text="03:16" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/screenShareContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myStatusContainer"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/myButtonContainer">

        <PinchandZoomLayout
            android:id="@+id/screenShareVideo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/black"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/screenShareToggle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_video_cam_switch" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/myStatusContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#AA555555"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myNameText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/gray6"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            tools:text="user2@gmail.com" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/myButtonVideoRotate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_video_cam_switch" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/groupList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/myButtonContainer"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activeSpeakerContainer">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/myProgressContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/groupList"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/groupList"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/groupList"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/groupList">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myProgressName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/gray6"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            tools:text="My Name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myProgressText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/myProgressName"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/my_status_connecting"
            android:textColor="@color/gray6"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/myButtonContainer"
        layout="@layout/layout_my_button_bar_1_row"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/myButtonContainerUnavailable"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/myButtonContainer"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/myButtonContainer"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/myButtonContainer"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/myButtonContainer"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/myButtonCancel"
            style="@style/myButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/btn_my_end"
            android:text="@string/dialog_button_cancel"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/myButtonRetry"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/myButtonRetry"
            style="@style/myButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/btn_my_retry"
            android:text="@string/button_try_again"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/myButtonCancel"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I just tried replacing "android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout" with relative layout but there's these parameters " app:layout_constraint..." which are more difficult to deal with.Any easier way to go around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need those parameters in Relative layout, so you can just remove them.

Comment: how will i position each container without them?i dont know if above,below topof,leftof etc will be as good

Comment: is there an automatic way studio converts it to relative layout, like it does for constraint layout

Comment: Relative layout need different tags like below, startOf etc which requires ids. So you give ids to views and then arrange other views in relation to those views with id's or you have options to arrange them in relation to parent as well e.g. align_parent_bottom. No android studio doesn't convert one layout to another.

Comment: See the supported tags [here] (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html).

Comment: Above, below, leftof etc are good enough and gets the job done but it actually depends on what are trying to achieve. If you can't do it with relative then you go for others like linear/constraint.

Comment: I would like to see how your `View` looks like so as to reproduce it by using `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, _why_ do you want to convert your ConstraintLayout to a RelativeLayout?

Comment: i have been seeing some ANR's while profiling which point to constraintlayout methods, so was wondering if switching it back to relativelayout will help aleviate the cpu usage?

Answer (score 5):

**I am using Android Studio version 3.1.2**

No need to do that much complex stuff.Just right click on 
layout name in component tree as shown in image and select option convert view and choose the layout which you want to use.

[image]